# Experimental evolution of condensates

Tags: statistical-mechanics, condensed-matter, experimental-physics, bose-einstein-condensate

I was talking to a colleague professor the other day and he said something that got me curious. The way I remember it, he said basically that in experiments a Bose-Einstein condensation is usually trapped by some external potential, which I imagine to be an electric or magnetic field. Then, the temperature is considerably lowered, the trap is turned off and one studies the evolution of this state.

Can someone further elaborate this kind of experiment? For instance, it was not clear to me what exactly one tries to measure with it; as far as I understood, the temperature is cooled down so to form a condensate in the first place and the release of the external field is intended to study its evolution. What one wants to understand with the evolution of such a condensate? Moreover, what material is used in such experiments? (I am thinking about liquid Hellium?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bose-Einstein condensates (BECs) of dilute gases are generated using magnetic traps or optical traps.
Once the traps is turned-off the BEC expands. This is usually where the fun begins and one can ask very fundamental questions. Like:

- BECs are said to be described by a single, macroscopic wave function. If that is true, does BECs interfere? Turns out: Yes! They do interfere: https://www.rle.mit.edu/cua_pub/ketterle_group/Projects_2004/Pubs_04/shin04_interferometry.pdf
- Can one stop the expansion somehow? Yes... some expansion remains, but calculating the temperature just from the expansion, one finds a corresponding temperture of 38 PICO kelvin! https://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.127.100401

Just two examples for today. I need to do some work

Comment: Ahh.. btw: One usually uses alkaline atoms, because of the simple atomic structure. Rubidium, Sodium and Potassium are mostly used.